# How to render more than 1 dialogs on Jupyterlab?

Tags: reactjs, jupyter-notebook, dialog, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using “host” property for dialogs so that they don’t cover the entire Jupyterlab tab and I can continue to do other things without closing the opened dialog. However while one dialog is open, any other dialog screen cannot be opened in the other parts of the application (different hosts).

If something is supposed to show dialog, it doesn’t until the open dialog somewhere else is closed.

Could you please tell me how I could fix this? I don’t think “host” property is just to visually render the dialog in different places. I believe it also gives us flexibility to use other parts of the application that is not covered by dialog without any interruption while the dialog is open and it should be able to show more than 1 dialog on the screen at the same time that has different hosts.

(asked on discourse as well: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-render-more-than-1-dialogs-on-jupyterlab/24818)